# Adding fields to table dynamically in django

Tags: mysql, django, database, database-design, django-models

After reading about database designs, i've decided to go with a single table for all users.

- my question is how can i create fields for new users to add their data into it?
- also what's a good approach for retrieving data specific to each user?

I appreciate any advise regarding this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Django, I would recommend reading the Django documentation and/or their getting started tutorials - they have really easy to follow guides on their website. Part 2 of their guide is probably what you're looking for (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/), but I would start reading from Part 1 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) - they're not very lengthy.

Django provides ORM functionality similar to other ORM frameworks. **So in order to automatically generate tables**, you need to first define what are called "models" in your Django files that directly map to tables in your MySQL database. In your case, you would define a model called "users".

Once you have defined your model, you can use the python CLI "makemigrations" command to automatically generate the related migration file for the users model. Migrations are the intermediary files that help Django create the associated tables in the database.

**As for retrieving data from the database** (that is specific to each user), you would have to write a set of endpoints in Django that will automatically run the appropriate SQL commands on your database and return the data that was found. For example, you might have an endpoint called *getAllUsers* that will map to a python (Django) function, which will retrieve all user data from the users table and return it.

The Django documentation explains how to **make queries** to your database. Check out this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for explanation, i forgot to mention that i already have a database and have no problem getting the tables the way you said, what i'm looking for, is to restructure my db so all users will be added in one table, so they have to be added dynamically. i'm looking for a way that i can separate each user specific data in that one table, from other users, so i can get the user data using a query.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand the problem you're describing. If you have a users table, you would have multiple columns in that table. For example, you might have "firstname", "lastname", "username", "password", "dateofbirth", etc. Everytime you add a new user to that table, you would provide the user's first name, last name, username, password and date of birth. That way, in the table you would have a single row for each user that exists (and each row would contain those five pieces of info). Is this the setup you currently have? If so, can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, currently i have one model with 40 fields for each user, so if i have 100 users, i have 100 models. what i want to do is to add all users to only one table. now this way how can i dynamically(when server is running) add  fields(users) to that one table. also how can i know what fields belong to what user if i want to get a user data using a query from that one table. this approach is already being used by industries though.